# JList set to ArrayList, show preset title

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` which is set to an `ArrayList` of days.

```
public void setCalender(ArrayList<Day> calender) {
    this.calender = calender;
    listDays.setListData(this.calender.toArray());
}
```

Each day contains a date/id and 3 periods:

```
public class Day {
    private int date;
    private Period p1;
    private Period p2;
    private Period p3;

    public Day(int date) {
        this.date = date;
        p1 = new Period(1);
        p2 = new Period(2);
        p3 = new Period(3);
    }
}
```

When the list renders, it shows each list item as "kkbs.Day@4d182e1e" for instance.
Is there any way to make a fixed string to show the user (i.e Day1), while still keeping the whole object in the list to retrieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom [cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for the list to format the view as required.  Alternately you might define a `toString()` for the object, but the renderer is more versatile.

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) capable of portraying your data the way you want it

Checkout [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information

Answer (score 3):

Override the toString method in your Day class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Day" + date.toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to override `toString()` method after extending jList to your own list.

Answer (score 2):

Simply override the `toString()` method, along the lines of

```
public String toString()
{
    return "whatever string representation of your day class it is you want to return";
}
```

The default implementation of `toString` will return `objectName@hashCode`.